# View [layout.layout] not found on hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I tired to push my Laravel app to hosting.
Soo I changed all content in .env for DB and now I get this error:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
   View [layout.layout] not found. (View: /home/ramchca/ftp/resources/views/Pages/index.blade.php)
    Previous exceptions

   View [layout.layout] not found. (0)
```

My question is. Why it doesn't work. On localhost all is working fine.

Comment: Is there a file at `/home/ramchca/ftp/resources/views/layout/layout.blade.php` (or `layout.php`)?

Comment: Yes there is that file

Comment: Is it readable by the webserver user?

Comment: Yep it is readable. I changed pressmisions on every file for 777

Comment: Also i tired on 2 different hostings and error is the same

Comment: How are you including this `layout.layout`?

Comment: @extends('layout.layout')

Comment: Are you sure it is `layout` not `layouts`?

Comment: Yes. I have files the same on hosting as on localhost and on localhost all works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I know what I did wrong.
My problem was lowercase at here

`@extends('layout.layout')`

folder was `Layout`.

Comment: Yeah, Linux is case-sensitive. Be careful - you'll have similar issues with things like `use App\User` versus `App\user`, so you'll want to make sure your case matches all over.

Answer (score -1):

Make .htaccess in your laravel directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm not sure, but you can try.